# Using a trigger to implement a foreign key check constraint

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, foreign-keys

I'm trying to implement this constraint into my database:
(In the table Race)
CONSTRAINT (Date <= Meeting.EndDate)

Essentially the column in the Race Table needs to be Less than the EndDate column in the Meeting table.

Pretty sure I need to use a trigger to implement a foreign key however, I'm not that sure how I would go about implementing one. So Far, All I have is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RaceDateCheck
AFTER UPDATE OF Race ON StartDateCheck
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Race
    (MeetingEndDate)
 SELECT EndDate FROM Meeting
END;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm, just realised this sounds familiar... rather like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22013628/266304). Interesting that both are trying to insert inside the trigger; have you been told to do that?

Comment: Looks like that person is on the same course as me. And yes, we've been specifically told to use triggers rather than just add additional columns to the tables we've been given.

Comment: Yes, but you both had an `insert` inside the trigger, which is invalid; just wondering if you'd been taught (incorrectly) to do that.

Comment: Don't think so, this is a mix of me googling answers and trying to decipher the lecture notes, mostly just trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the race date has to be between the meeting start and end date, so you could check both at once; and also presumably you want to check this for new records, not just updates. So you could use something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RaceDateCheck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Race
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  meetingStart Meeting.MeetingStartDate%TYPE;
  meetingEnd Meeting.MeetingEndDate%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT StartDate, EndDate
  INTO meetingStart, meetingEnd
  FROM Meeting
  WHERE MeetingID = :NEW.MeetingID;

  IF :NEW.RaceDate < meetingStart
    OR :NEW.RaceDate > meetingEnd THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Invalid race date');
  END IF;
END;
```

For just the end date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RaceDateCheck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Race
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  meetingEnd Meeting.MeetingEndDate%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT EndDate
  INTO meetingEnd
  FROM Meeting
  WHERE MeetingID = :NEW.MeetingID;

  IF :NEW.RaceDate > meetingEnd THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Invalid race date');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the MeetingStart Date is already present in the table I'm using; so I've already got that check constraint working - if I were to remove all references to MeetingStart in this; will it all still work?

Comment: @Naffel - yes it will. Having the meeting start date duplicated for each race is odd though.

Comment: Righto thanks, I'll test it out once I get my VPN working again.

Comment: It seems to be throwing up errors and I'm not sure that this is what I need to achieve. I'm putting this in with the scripts that applies constraints to my created tables (in another script). I need to be able to add these constraints and drop them at will and there doesn't seem to be a way I can test that something permanent is being set.

Comment: If the trigger is enabled then inserting or updating a row with a bad date will raise an exception, yes. But that isn't so different from what a check constraint will do? You can drop or disable the trigger, of course. There is a significant difference though; creating or enabling the trigger will *not* validate existing data in the table; and if the meeting dates change then dates in the race table will not be revalidated.