# Using a trigger in place of a foreign key

Tags: oracle, triggers, sqlplus

The practice question goes like this:

Implement triggers which perform the same function as the
following foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Sample ADD CONSTRAINT sample_fk
FOREIGN KEY (tissue_type_id) 
    REFERENCES Tissue_Type(tissue_type_id);
```

Where `tissue_type_id` is an attribute in both tables `Sample` and `tissue_type`.

Following the format from

[Using a trigger to implement a foreign key check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129704/using-a-trigger-to-implement-a-foreign-key-check-constraint)

So far I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tissue_type_inck
BEFORE INSERT ON SAMPLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    tissueType tissue_type.tissue_type_id%TYPE;

    SELECT TISSUE_TYPE_ID
        INTO tissueType
    FROM TISSUE_TYPE
    WHERE TISSUE_TYPE_ID=:NEW.TISSUE_TYPE_ID;

    IF :NEW.TISSUE_TYPE_ID != tissueType THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'INVALID TISSUE TYPE');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I get the compilation error:

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Where am I going wrong? Sorry for formatting and thanks!

Comment: Ok, i you really are on Oracle, I've made an update to my post

Comment: After you fix the trigger for insertions, don't forget that foreign keys have to do with updates as well (and with updates and deletions on the PK table).

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    tissueType tissue_type.tissue_type_id%TYPE;
```

It's on the other way :

```
DECLARE 
    tissueType tissue_type.tissue_type_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
```